# replace gelfpro with @fluent-org/logger isn't sending logs to fluentd service

Tags: fluentd

We have a fluentd service running behind a Load balancer.
At present, we are sending logs by using gelf pro js package

```
gelfPro.setConfig({
  fields: { appName: 'niyazapp' },
  adapterName: 'tcp',
  transform: [
    (message) => {
      message.log = message.short_message;
      return message;
    },
  ],
  adapterOptions: {
    protocol: 'tcp4',
    host: "logrouter.niyaz.io",
    port: "12201",
  },
});
gelfPro.info("Hello world from niyaz");
```

Now, i am trying to replace the gelfpro js library with @fluent-org/logger

```
const FluentClient = require("@fluent-org/logger").FluentClient;
const flDlogger = new FluentClient("fallthrough.test", {
    eventMode: "Message",
    socket: {
      host: "logrouter.niyaz.io",
      port: "12201",
      timeout: 3000,
    }
  });
await flDlogger.connect();
await flDlogger.emit({
          "version": "1.1",
          "short_message": "Hello world from nashe",
          "timestamp": 1689855638.23,
          "level": 6,
          "_appName": "nashfluentd",
          "_log": "Hello world from nashfluentd"
        }));
```

And the logs are not sending, am i missing anything ?